# Complex text (curve) to mesh creates gaps

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a logo based on a complex font that I want to 3D-ize. When I convert the 2D text object (created in Blender or imported as SVG - same result) I get a mesh that has a log of gaps in it, which is really visible when you extrude it. Some of the gaps seem to come from the curve intersecting (itself), but not all... What can I do to get it as a solid/continuous object?

[image: Curve]
[image: Mesh]
[image: Mesh closeup]
[image: Extrude]

Comment: Use Remesh modifyer. Letters are notorious for topology issues.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth Thanks, will try!

Comment: Didn't help... But I did find out what I did wrong and solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Using extrude in the font properties in Blender proved to be the right way.

In my question I had created a text, then converted to mesh and finally extruded with 'e' - that created the broken mesh. A lot of unnecessary steps that also rendered a bad result.

[image]